# Mercurial, check if a particular version of a file has existed in the history before?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

To somewhat elaborate on the title question, is there a way to have Mercurial search through the repository history for a particular version of a given file, and show all of the revisions (or just the most recent one) that contain that version?

For example, let's say that the current working revision is, say, `300` and a file was reverted to an earlier version (say, revision `200`). I don't know this - all I can easily see is "how different" the new file is from the `300` version. How can I find out all of the possible revisions that it could have been reverted to?

And if Mercurial cannot do this natively, is there another tool that can? (TortoiseHG?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't *think* this is possible with any of hg's built-in functionality, but you can get something like it with judicious xargs and md5sum application:

```
hg log --template "{rev}\\n" | xargs -I "{}" /bin/bash -c 'echo $(hg cat -r {} <filename> | md5sum) {}'
```

This will give you a list of md5 checksums with the revision number, which when you sort it will give you the revisions sharing versions of the file.

Comment: This is good! Granted, with thousands of revisions, this may take a bit too long, but with smaller repositories it is more than feasible. Thanks!